# Module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, recursion, import

I am trying to import my module `import { waitProp } from 'wait-prop';`

And i have this error

```sh
ERROR in ./src/app/qr-scanner/qr-scanner.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Recursion in resolving
Stack:
  resolve: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/src/app/qr-scanner) wait-prop
  newResolve: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/src/app/qr-scanner) wait-prop
  parsedResolve: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/src/app/qr-scanner) wait-prop module
  describedResolve: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/src/app/qr-scanner) wait-prop module
  rawModule: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/src/app/qr-scanner) wait-prop
  module: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/src/app/qr-scanner) wait-prop
  resolve: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/node_modules) ./wait-prop
  newResolve: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/node_modules) ./wait-prop
  parsedResolve: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/node_modules) ./wait-prop
  describedResolve: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/node_modules) ./wait-prop
  relative: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/node_modules/wait-prop) 
  describedRelative: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/node_modules/wait-prop) 
  rawFile: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/node_modules/wait-prop) 
  file: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/web-tools/node_modules/wait-prop) 
  relative: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/wait-prop) 
  describedRelative: (/Users/gkucmierz/workspace/wait-prop)
```

This is my angular version:

```sh
ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.0.0
Node: 14.4.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.0.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.0
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.0
@angular/cdk                      10.0.0
@angular/cli                      10.0.0
@angular/material                 10.0.0
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.0
@schematics/angular               10.0.0
@schematics/update                0.1000.0
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.5
webpack                           4.43.0
```

What can be wrong here?

I don`t know what should I write yet to not make it look like this post is mostly code.
I did add many details including my environment versions.

Comment: Running into the same problem, oddly enough it only happens in my CI environment. When I build locally it works fine.

Comment: I just had the same exact error. I'm developing a reusable module as an NPM package, and using npm link to add it to node_modules. If you're doing that too, or otherwise symlinking your module into another project, I can post an answer. (Or, it could be an entirely different cause)

Comment: +1, getting this error in my CI environment where node_modules are symlinked. I found a related issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18021) which is marked as resolved, but it seems like the issue persists in version 10.0.2

Answer (score 3):

Like @circleofconfusion, I am effectively seeing this on my CI (and also a docker container which does some things to my `node_modules` folder that are likely also to happen on a CI).

I found the argument `--preserveSymlinks` when passed to `ng test` (that is where I am seeing the error) will break the recursion (fix) resolving the module I was having an error with.

You will find this argument in https://angular.io/cli/build and you can edit your `angular.json` to set the property so you don't need to specify it on the commandline. You will need to add it to the `options` block in each of the problematic builders (likely in any of the builders that start with "@angular-devkit/build-angular") . This will tell angular to not resolve the symlinks to their actual path, and fixes the issue I have (my `node_modules` is actually symlinked to a shared location)

Hope this helps!